# What does adding an integer to a pointer do?

Tags: c

I am trying to understand this program.

The code is:

```
ActiveBuffer->length += sprintf(
            ActiveBuffer->data + ActiveBuffer->length,
            "\"Timestamp[ms]\":%lld,\n", timestamp);
```

where ActiveBuffer is:

```
Buffer *ActiveBuffer;
```

and `Buffer` is defined as:

```
typedef struct {
    int32_t length;
    char data[BUFFSIZE];
} Buffer;
```

I know that the function sprintf writes data to the buffer but I am unable to understand the addition `ActiveBuffer->data + ActiveBuffer->length`.

Comment: ActiveBuffer->data is the base address and ActiveBuffer->length is how many characters were already written so basically it s the offset to write on

Comment: You should read up on [*pointer arithmetic*](https://www.google.com/search?q=pointer+arithmetic).  Addition and subtraction of integers to/from pointers, and subtraction of pointers from pointers from pointers (yielding integers) are all very useful and very well defined in C, operating in terms of the individual pointed-to items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of `ActiveBuffer->data + ActiveBuffer->length` as `&ActiveBuffer->data[ActiveBuffer->length]`. It's an offset into the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

ActiveBuffer->data is the pointer to the first element of array, ActiveBuffer->length is a integer, the + operator acts as offset the pointer to the number of (ActiveBuffer->length)'th element.In other word, every time you write to the ActiveBuffer->data, it is appended, instead of overwrite. But make sure the BUFFSIZE shall be big enough to serve your purpose.